# Error while running reactjs app under pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pm2

I have reactjs project that need to be run on the linux server. Whenever I run the app on server using "sudo npm run lin_stage_server" it seems to be working fine on 80 port.
when I tried to run app through pm2 with command "sudo pm2 start npm -- lin_stage_server" its not working for me.

In addition to the above command i also tried
"sudo pm2 start npm -- BRANCH_ENV=stage NODE_ENV=production PORT=80 node appserverstart.js
"

Please help !

----- Error details ------

[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhQiL.png)

----- Package.json -----

[Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj3xr.png)

----- appserverstart.js -----

[appserverstart.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ2cm.png)

-------Additional info------- 
server: CentOS Linux version 7 core, 
npm version: 6.4.1, 
pm2 version: 3.5.1, 
node version: 8.11.1,

Comment: Please add text, not screenshots. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `run` to npm:

```
pm2 start npm -- run lin_stage_server
```

---

`pm2 start npm -- lin_stage_server` is effectively `npm lin_stage_server`.

`pm2 start npm -- run lin_stage_server` is effectively `npm run lin_stage_server`